# Problema de navegación Dinamica con states React js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, menú

bien es el primer front end que hago con react, soy consiente de que los componentes no estan bien organizados, tengo un problema a ver si alguien con mas experiencia con los states me puede ayudar, les dejo el repositorio para que lo vean: https://github.com/mpadula1990/yangsoft.git

El problema es que tengo un menú a la izquierda el cual carga componentes según en que menú apriete el usuario. Por alguna razón al navegar "hacia delante" el state se modifica y carga correctamente el menú pero al querer volver hacia otro menú no carga.
Les dejo los archivos implicados a ver si lo ven mejor que yo:

**- archivo con un array que corresponde al menu.**

> yangsoft/src/Data/Settings/MenuDash.js

**- En este folder estan todos los componentes que se cargan.**

> yangsoft/src/Components/DashBoard/BoardComponents/WorkSection/

**- y aqui los JS implicados al menu.**

> src/Components/Global/MenuDash.js
>
> /src/Components/Global/DropDownMenu.js
>
> src/Components/DashBoard/index.js

Les dejo por aqui tambien el codigo que pienso que esta dando problemas:
DropDownMenu.js

```
// Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//Data
import MENU from '../../Data/Settings/MenuDash';

//Components
import Modal from "../Global/Modal";

class DropTownMenu extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: MENU.slice(),
    }

  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className='DropTownMenu'>

        {
          this.state.data.map((todo, i) =>

          <div>
              <li key={i} className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a onClick={ ()=>this.props.getSelectedItem(todo.url) } className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i className="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                  <span>{todo.menu}</span>
                </a>
                <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
                    {
                    Array.isArray(todo.items) && todo.items.map((item, j) => 
                      <a key={j} className="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target={'#'+item.destino}>{item.title}</a>
             
                    )}
                </div>
              </li>
              </div>
          )}
      <Modal idTarget='NuevoUsuario' modalTitle='Registro de nuevo usuario' ComponentName='FrmAltaUsuario' />
      <Modal idTarget='NuevoSocio' modalTitle='Registro de nuevo socio' ComponentName='FrmAltaSocios' />
      <Modal idTarget='SocioMembresia' modalTitle='Membresia del socio' ComponentName='FrmSocioMembresia' />
      <Modal idTarget='SocioMuestra' modalTitle='Muestras' ComponentName='FrmSocioMuestra' />
      <Modal idTarget='SocioRutina' modalTitle='Rutinas' ComponentName='FrmSocioRutinas' />
      <Modal idTarget='NuevaMembresia' modalTitle='Nueva membresia' ComponentName='FrmNuevaMembresia' />
      <Modal idTarget='NuevaClase' modalTitle='Nueva clase' ComponentName='FrmNuevaClase' />
      <Modal idTarget='NuevoProducto' modalTitle='Nuevo producto' ComponentName='FrmAltaProductos' />
      <Modal idTarget='NuevaCompra' modalTitle='Nueva Compra' ComponentName='FrmNuevaCompra' />
      <Modal idTarget='NuevaVenta' modalTitle='Nueva venta' ComponentName='FrmNuevaVenta' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DropTownMenu;
```

// MENU DASH COMPONENT (MenuDash.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Componetes
import DropTownMenu from './DropDownMenu';

//Assets
import "./MenuDash.css";
import "./fixes.scss"
//Data
class MenuDash extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      
        <ul className="sidebar navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item active">
            <a className="nav-link" href="/DashBoard">
              <i className="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <DropTownMenu getSelectedItem={(selectedOption)=> this.props.getSelectedOption(selectedOption) }/>
        </ul>
      

    );
  }
}
export default MenuDash;
```

Aqui donde renderizo el menu (index.js)

```
//Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './dash.scss';
// Components
import MainNav from '../Global/MainNav';
import MenuDash from '../Global/MenuDash';
import DashFooter from '../Global/DashFooter';
import ScrolToTop from '../Global/ScrolToTop';
import LogOutModal from '../Global/LogOutModal';
import Modal from '../Global/Modal';
import Home from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Home/home';
import Registro from './BoardComponents/Registro/registro';
import Socios from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Socios/socios';
import Config from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Config/config';
import Items from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Items/items';
import Lessons from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Lessons/lessons';
import Membership from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Membership/membership';
import Purchases from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Purchases/purchases';
import Reports from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Reports/reports';
import Sales from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Sales/sales';
import Statics from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Statics/statics';
import Users from './BoardComponents/WorkSection/Users/users';

// Fomrs Components

class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    showComponent: ''
  }
  renderDashBoard(){
    
    switch (this.state.showComponent) {
      case 'USERS':
        return <Users/>
      case 'PARTHNERS' :
        return  <Socios/>;
      case 'MEMBERSHIP':
        return <Membership/>;
      case 'LESSONS':
        return <Lessons/>;
      case 'ITEMS':
        return <Items/>
      case 'PURCHASES':
        return <Purchases/>;
      case 'SALES':
        return <Sales/>;
      case 'REGISTER':
        return <Registro/>;
      case 'STATICS':
        return <Statics/>;
      case 'REPORTS':
        return <Reports/>;
      case 'CONFIG':
        return <Config/>;
      default:
        return <Home/>
    }
  }
  render() {
      

    return (
      <div className="Dashboard">
        <div id="page-top">
          <MainNav />
          <div id="wrapper">
            <MenuDash getSelectedOption={(selectedOption)=> this.setState({showComponent:selectedOption},() => console.log(selectedOption)) }/>
              <div id="content-wrapper">
              {this.renderDashBoard()}
              <DashFooter />
            </div>
          </div>
          <ScrolToTop />
          <LogOutModal />
          <Modal idTarget='frmNuevaVenta' modalTitle='Nueva Venta' ComponentName='FrmNuevaVenta'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Y este es el objeto MENU que importo:

```
const MENU = [
  {
    'menu': 'Usuarios',
    'url' : 'USERS',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nuevo usuario',
        'destino' : 'NuevoUsuario'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Nuevo rol',
        'destino' : 'NuevoRol'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'menu': 'Socios',
    'url' : 'PARTHNERS',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nuevo',
        'destino' : 'NuevoSocio'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Membresias',
        'destino' : 'SocioMembresia'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Muestras',
        'destino' : 'SocioMuestra'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Rutinas',
        'destino' : 'SocioRutina'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'menu': 'Membresias',
    'url' : 'MEMBERSHIP',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nueva',
        'destino' : 'NuevaMembresia'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'menu': 'Clases',
    'url' : 'LESSONS',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nueva',
        'destino' : 'NuevaClase'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'menu': 'Productos',
    'url' : 'ITEMS',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nuevo',
        'destino' : 'NuevoProducto'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'menu': 'Compras',
    'url' : 'PURCHASES',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nueva',
        'destino' : 'NuevaCompra'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'menu': 'Ventas',
    'url' : 'SALES',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Nueva',
        'destino' : 'NuevaVenta'
      },
      {
        'title': 'Reimprimir',
        'destino' : 'Reimprecion'
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    'menu': 'Registro',
    'url':'REGISTER'
  },
  {
    'menu': 'Estadisticas',
    'url':'STATICS'
  },
  {
    'menu': 'Reportes',
    'url': 'REPORTS'
  },
  {
    'menu': 'Configurar',
    'url':'CONFIG',
    'items':[
      {
        'title': 'Configuracion',
        'destino' : 'Config'
      }
    ]
  }
]
export default MENU;
```

Tal vez vean lo que yo no, seguramente debe ser un error causado por inexperiencia en React. Muchas a gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. en español. ¿podrías por favor agregar el código que encuentras que tiene problemas a la pregunta en vez de agregar el link a tu proyecto? así quienes quieran responder tu pregunta no tengan que buscar en el código que tú conoces mejor que nadie. De pasada podrías revisar el articulo de [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: Pienso que para esos casos deberias usar react-router-dom

Comment: si tal vez sea lo mejor, gracias